Composition of linear maps is one-to-one and onto, then individual maps are one-to-one and onto.
Let $V$, $W$, and $Z$ be vector spaces, and let $T \in \mathcal{L}(V,W)$, $U \in \mathcal{L}(W,Z)$ be linear maps.
I've been able to prove that if $UT$ is one-to-one, then so is $T$; if $UT$ is onto, then so is $U$. But what about $U$ when $UT$ is one-to-one, and $T$ when $UT$ is onto? Are they also one-to-one and onto, respectively? Intuitively I think they are not, but I cannot disprove or come up with a concrete counterexample...

Side comment: this exact same phenomenon occurs with just maps between sets—the restriction to linear maps isn't a key point at all.

Intuition aid: what if the dimensions of $V,W,Z$ are $1,0,1$, respectively?  Then it's easy for $U$ to be $1$-to-$1$ and impossible for $V$.  What if the dimensions are $0,1,0$, respectively?  Then it's easy for $U$ to be onto and impossible for $V$.

No. A standard example is to take $V=Z=\mathbb{R}$, $W=\mathbb{R}^2$, let $T\colon V\to W$ be $T(x) = (x,0)$, and $U\colon W\to Z$ be given by $U(x,y)=x$.
Then $UT\colon V\to Z$ is given by $UT(x) = x$, which is one-to-one and onto;  but $U$ is not one-to-one, and $T$ is not onto.

Some matrices showing an example of the type Arturo mentions: the beginning and ending vector spaces have dimension 2, but the middle one has dimension 3.
$$
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 2 & -2\\ 
2 & 1 & 2 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rr} 
1 & 2 \\ 
2 & 1 \\
-2 & 2 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rr} 
9 & 0 \\ 
0 & 9 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
To get the product coming out as the identity matrix, just divide every entry in the rectangles by 3
